# QT connect function for status bar

Tags: qt, connect, text-editor

I'm trying to make a notepad-like app in QT c++, and right now I'm trying to implement a simple status bar that tells the user the Line and the Column of the cursor.

I've been using the connect function like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)

{
    connect(ui->textEdit, SIGNAL(cursorPositionChanged()), this, SLOT(MainWindow::showCursorPosition()));
.
.
}
```

And I have the showCursorPosition method defined like this:

```
void MainWindow::showCursorPosition(){
    int line = ui->textEdit->textCursor().blockNumber()+1;
    int column = ui->textEdit->textCursor().columnNumber()+1;
    ui->statusBar->showMessage(QString("Line %1  Column %2").arg(line).arg(column));
}
```

The method works, I am pretty sure because I called it from the constructor and it shows "Line 1 Column 1" in the status bar.

But the connect function doesn't seem to work properly, and I can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old (`Qt4`) syntax doesn't understand `C++` namespaces.  Change the `connect` call to...

```
connect(ui->textEdit, SIGNAL(cursorPositionChanged()),
        this, SLOT(showCursorPosition()));
```

Alternatively, if you're using `Qt5` you should make use of the newer signal/slot syntax...

```
connect(ui->textEdit, &QTextEdit::cursorPositionChanged,
        this, &MainWindow::showCursorPosition);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work either way, It just doesn't call the method.I'm using the Qt 5.9 MinGw debugger

Comment: I've been meddling a little bit, and I found something in the  console.QObject::connect: invalid null parameter

Comment: That would suggest that `ui->textEdit` is `nullptr` within the context of the `MainWindow` ctor.  Should be easy to check.

Comment: It works, I just needed to put the connect line after the setup...easy fix. Silly me.